# How to execute JS after saving a model in DB in Rails 6?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I’m Rails beginner and I’m a bit overwhelmed by the quite simple problem. I would like to do something like this:

1. Users fills in a form.
2. Taps on the submit button
3. Model is saved into database.
4. If the save operation was successful, execute a javascript.

The questions is: how to accomplish that in the best way possible in Rails 6? Should I use `.js.erb` files? Or should I have javascript put into webpacker?

I tried so far the following code, but without any success:

**controller/jobs_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @job = current_user.jobs.build(job_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @job.save
      format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Success!' }
      format.js {}
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

**views/jobs/create.js.erb**

```
alert('hello');
```

Comment: js.erb files should work, but you need to use `remote: true` on the form

Comment: "Should I use .js.erb files? Or should I have javascript put into webpacker?". Thats a question of opinion. The former lets you reuse your rails views but results in some pretty horrible code. The later encourages you to write actual javascript and think about creating a  RESTful API instead of a bunch of "manipulate_x_doodad" garbage routes in your application.

Comment: @maxpleaner Ah right, I was missing `remote: true` in the form tag. Thanks!

Comment: "The later encourages you to write actual javascript and think about creating a RESTful API" 
@max Do you know about any good example code with this approach? It would be great to learn more about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was pointed out by @max-pleaner I was missing `remote: true` in the `form` tag.